# How to install drivers for nvidia GPU and amd APU?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, ati

Im trying an install of APU drivers along with GPU drivers. I need GPU for rendering, just one monitor would be used, driven by APU.

Using ubuntu 14.04 64 bits, I get (lscpci):

```
  00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kaveri [Radeon R7 200 Series]
  01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 13c2 (rev a1)
```

What I have tried already:

1. Install propietary drivers for apu
2. Reboot, seems it worked ok
3. Install Nvidia drivers, got problems loging in again

Had a look at xorg.conf there was only nvidia driver, no more fglrx.

APU is from AMD A8 cpu
GPU is Nvidia gtx 970

How can I run both drivers?

Comment: I once saw this method: 1. copy original empty xorg.conf driver to backup #1. 2. install 1st driver. 3. when works copy xorg.conf over to a backup #2. 4. remove driver/reinstall  xorg.conf backup #1. 5. install 2nd driver. 6. when works copy xorg.conf to backup #3. 7. Merge xorg.conf backup #2 with backup #3 to make a new xorg.conf. ... Good luck with it ;-)

Comment: Thans Rinzwind, will give it a try. When you mention remove driver you mean as sudo-apt remove?